# Docker for windows, docker wont run the image, it just hangs

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to get started with docker but for some reason, it does not start the image and just hangs. I downloaded the hello world image from docker hub. My OS is windows 10 64bit. I dont know where to find any docker logs. I am using windows containers. Is there something I am missing?

I tried running the same commands in powershell and it just hangs.

I want to use windows containers as you can see the setting below is switch to linux

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe the image is corrupt; delete the image with `docker rmi <id-of-image>` and start again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I downloaded the image from the docker hub. this is the url for the image https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/

Comment: any small working image, you guys can advise to download and try if it runs?

Comment: the hello world image does run here on three different systems

Comment: :( I dont know what else to check for...

Comment: Anything in your Windows eventlog? Did you uninstall and install *Docker for Windows* again? Do other images work?

Comment: The event log just says "debug: Calling GET /v1.37/containers/json?limit=0"

Comment: The event log just says "debug: Calling GET /v1.37/containers/json?limit=0" I also did uninstall docker and reinstall it. I downloaded this image also "https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/' I then tried to docker run this image and I get the same in event viewer "debug: Calling GET /v1.37/containers/json?limit=0". It just hangs

Comment: What Windows 10 Version do you got? Home, Professional, Enterprise?

Comment: Win 10 Pro, 64bit, i7, 8gb ram

Comment: any other ideas ?